# Exception Handling

Tags: java, file, exception

I'm writing a program that is supposed to create a triangle and throw an exception if the triangle is not legal, meaning that the sum of any two sides must be greater than the length of the remaining side. The program consists of 4 classes (the super class GeometricObject, a Triangle class, a Program6 class, and an IllegalTriangleException class). The program is supposed to read in data from a file that consists of the lengths for each side, the color, and whether it's filled or not, perform calculations to determine the perimeter and area, and write the information to a file entitled prog6.out. I haven't implemented the writing to a file yet though since I'm having some problems getting the program to display the results correctly using a regular print statement since implementing the IllegalTriangleException class.

Here is what I have so far: The GeometricObject Class:

```
public class GeometricObject {
    private String color = "white";
    private boolean filled;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;

    public GeometricObject() {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }

    public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean isFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Created on: " + dateCreated + "\nColor: " + color + "\nFilled: " + filled;
    }
}
```

The Triangle class:

```
public class Triangle extends GeometricObject {
    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;
    private double s = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;
    private double area = Math.sqrt(s*(s-side1)*(s-side2)*(s-side3));
    private double perimeter;

    public Triangle() {
        side1 = 1.0;
        side2 = 1.0;
        side3 = 1.0;
    }

    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
        this.side1 = side1;
        this.side2 = side2;
        this.side3 = side3;
    }

    public double getSide1() {
        return side1;
    }

    public double getSide2() {
        return side2;
    }

    public double getSide3() {
        return side3;
    }



    public double getPerimeter() {
        return (side1 + side2 + side3);
    }

    public double getArea() {
        this.s = (side1 + side2 + side3)/2;
        this.area = Math.sqrt(s*(s-side1)*(s-side2)*(s-side3));
        return area;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Triangle: " + "\nSide 1: " + side1 + "\nSide2: " + side2 + "\nSide3: " + side3 + "\nArea: " + getArea() + "\nPerimeter: " + getPerimeter() + "\nColor: " + getColor() + "\nFilled: " + isFilled();
    }

    public void setSides(double newSide1, double newSide2, double newSide3) throws IllegalTriangleException {
        if (side1 + side2 > side3){
            if (side1 + side3 > side2)
                if (side2 + side3 > side1)
        side1 = newSide1;
        side2 = newSide2;
        side3 = newSide3;
        }
        else
            throw new IllegalTriangleException(newSide1, newSide2, newSide3);
    }

    public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3, String color, boolean filled) throws IllegalTriangleException {
        try {
            setSides(getSide1(), getSide2(), getSide3());
        }
        catch(IllegalTriangleException ex) {
            System.out.println("Illegal Triangle: The summ of any two sides must be greater than the other side" + side1 + "," + side2 + "," + side3);
        }
    }
}
```

The Program6 class:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Program6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("prog6.dat");
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(file);

        while (fin.hasNext()) {
            double side1 = fin.nextDouble();
            double side2 = fin.nextDouble();
            double side3 = fin.nextDouble();
            String color = fin.next();
            String bool = fin.next();
            boolean filled;
             if(bool.equals("T"))
                  filled = true;
             else
                  filled = false;
            Triangle triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3, color, filled);
            System.out.println(triangle);
        }
        fin.close();
    }
}
```

And the IllegalTriangleException class:

```
public class IllegalTriangleException extends Exception {

    private double side1;
    private double side2;
    private double side3;

    public IllegalTriangleException() {
    }

    public IllegalTriangleException(double side1, double side2, double side3) {
        super("Illegal Triangle: The summ of any two sides must be greater than the other side" + side1 + "," + side2 + "," + side3);
        //this.side1 = side1;
        //this.side2 = side2;
        //this.side3 = side3;
    }

    public double getSide1() {
        return side1;
    }

    public double getSide2() {
        return side2;
    }

    public double getSide3() {
        return side3;
    }
}
```

And in case it helps, here is the file that is being used for the input:

```
1.0 1.5 1.0 yellow  T
3.0 4.0 5.0 blue F
2.4 1.1 1.2 red T
3.1 6.2 8.5 green T
1.2 9.9 4.5 cyan F
```

Before adding in the Exception class, the program was working properly, the file was being read correctly and assigning the correct values to the variables, and the area and perimeters were being calculated correctly, however, now that I've added in the exception class, here is my output:

```
Illegal Triangle: The summ of any two sides must be greater than the other side1.0,1.5,1.0
Triangle: 
Side 1: 0.0
Side2: 0.0
Side3: 0.0
Area: 0.0
Perimeter: 0.0
Color: white
Filled: false
Illegal Triangle: The summ of any two sides must be greater than the other side3.0,4.0,5.0
Triangle: 
Side 1: 0.0
Side2: 0.0
Side3: 0.0
Area: 0.0
Perimeter: 0.0
Color: white
Filled: false
Illegal Triangle: The summ of any two sides must be greater than the other side2.4,1.1,1.2
Triangle: 
Side 1: 0.0
Side2: 0.0
Side3: 0.0
Area: 0.0
Perimeter: 0.0
Color: white
Filled: false
Illegal Triangle: The summ of any two sides must be greater than the other side3.1,6.2,8.5
Triangle: 
Side 1: 0.0
Side2: 0.0
Side3: 0.0
Area: 0.0
Perimeter: 0.0
Color: white
Filled: false
Illegal Triangle: The summ of any two sides must be greater than the other side1.2,9.9,4.5
Triangle: 
Side 1: 0.0
Side2: 0.0
Side3: 0.0
Area: 0.0
Perimeter: 0.0
Color: white
Filled: false
```

Not sure what I've done wrong, if anyone can help me out it'd be much appreciated. This is the first time I've worked with this many classes and also the first time I've worked with exception handling, so please be nice :-)

Comment: Why are you not setting the side1/side2/side3 values in the exception object?

Comment: And what do you expect to happen, given that you catch the exception inside Triangle and don't return any error indication?  You should have the try/catch around the `new Triangle` call in `main`, then print the error message in the `catch` handler there, extracting the side info from the exception.

Comment: To draw attention to MadProgrammer's "Third" point, if you say you're a beginner right now, never omit curly braces for exactly that type of reason. Even some seasoned developers keep them in for one line conditions, just to eliminate the possibility of that kind of error.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Thanks to the answer below I was able to get it working properly, however I'm wondering if there's a way to only print the exception when it's thrown, not print the "illegal" triangle. After making the corrections, the exception is thrown in the right places, however it's still printing those triangles, only setting the values to the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three basic problems...

### First...

In your `Triangle` constructor, you are passing `getSide1()`, `getSide2()` and `getSide3()` to the `setSides` method...

```
public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3, String color, boolean filled) throws IllegalTriangleException {
    try {
        setSides(getSide1(), getSide2(), getSide3());
```

This means, you are simply passing the values of the fields `side1`, `side2` and `side3`, which haven't been set yet are defaulted to `0`, which means you are effectively saying...

```
setSides(0d, 0d, 0d);
```

This needs to be changed to pass the parameters of the constructor, for example...

```
public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3, String color, boolean filled) throws IllegalTriangleException {
    try {
        setSides(side1, side2, side3);
```

### Second...

Your `setSides` method is testing the state of the instance fields `state1`, `state2` and `state3`, which haven't been set yet (and even correcting for the previous mistake) are still defaulted to `0`...so `0 + 0 > 0` is ... `false`

```
public void setSides(double newSide1, double newSide2, double newSide3) throws IllegalTriangleException {
    if (side1 + side2 > side3){
        if (side1 + side3 > side2)
            if (side2 + side3 > side1)
```

This should be modified to use the values passed to the method instead...

```
public void setSides(double newSide1, double newSide2, double newSide3) throws IllegalTriangleException {
    if (newSide1 + newSide2 > newSide3)
        if (newSide1 + newSide3 > newSide2)
            if (newSide2 + newSide3 > newSide1)
```

### Third...

The previous `if` statement is wrong.  What this basically equates to saying is, if everything is fine, set `side1 = newSide1` and regardless of anything else, set `side2` and `side3` to `newSide2` and `newSide3` respectivly...

```
public void setSides(double newSide1, double newSide2, double newSide3) throws IllegalTriangleException {
    if (newSide1 + newSide2 > newSide3) 
        if (newSide1 + newSide3 > newSide2)
            if (newSide2 + newSide3 > newSide1)
                side1 = newSide1;

    side2 = newSide2;
    side3 = newSide3;
```

This is why it's VERY important to use `{...}`, for example...

```
public void setSides(double newSide1, double newSide2, double newSide3) throws IllegalTriangleException {
    if (newSide1 + newSide2 > newSide3) {
        if (newSide1 + newSide3 > newSide2) {
            if (newSide2 + newSide3 > newSide1) {
                side1 = newSide1;
                side2 = newSide2;
                side3 = newSide3;
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalTriangleException(newSide1, newSide2, newSide3);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is, the `IllegalTriangleException` will only be raised when `newSide1 + newSide2 > newSide3`, this can be rectified by testing each condition in a single `if` statement, for example...

```
public void setSides(double newSide1, double newSide2, double newSide3) throws IllegalTriangleException {
    if (newSide1 + newSide2 > newSide3 && 
            newSide1 + newSide3 > newSide2 &&
            newSide2 + newSide3 > newSide1) {
        side1 = newSide1;
        side2 = newSide2;
        side3 = newSide3;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalTriangleException(newSide1, newSide2, newSide3);
    }
}
```

No offense, but a good IDE should have picked up the issue with the `if` statements and a debugger would have helped find the other problems...

### Additional...

The `Triangle` constructor is smothering the `IllegalTriangleException`, this means that it is never thrown to the caller...

```
public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3, String color, boolean filled) throws IllegalTriangleException {
    try {
        setSides(side1, side2, side3);(IllegalTriangleException ex) {
        System.out.println("Illegal Triangle: The summ of any two sides must be greater than the other side" + side1 + "," + side2 + "," + side3);
    }
}
```

Remove the `try-catch` and let the caller deal with it...

```
public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3, String color, boolean filled) throws IllegalTriangleException {
    setSides(side1, side2, side3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm using Eclipse but it didn't give me any errors.

Comment: It may not give you errors, but I would hope it would be giving editor warnings/suggestions.  I picked the `if` statement issue up because I reformatted the code in Netbeans and I have Netbeans set to always use `{...}` around `if` statements ;)

Comment: Good tip, I"ll have to do that, thanks. This worked perfectly, however I'm wondering if there's a way to only let it print the "legal" triangles, in other words, if the exception is thrown, only print the exception message? After writing in your corrections, it's throwing the exception at the right times, but it's still printing those triangles, only with the default values.

Comment: Based on your original code, technically, it shouldn't be, because when an `Exception` is raised, it should be exiting the `main` method

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Yeah, it's printing the Illegal Triangle message, but then printing Side 1: 0.0, Side 2: 0.0 and so on.

Comment: Sorry my bad, found it

Comment: Sorry, I know it's a lot of code, but since the classes all work off of each other, I figured I better include everything.

Comment: The problem is in the `Triangle` constructor, check the update to the question for details

Comment: Ok that fixed that, but I still want it to print the remaining legal triangles, adding in this correction stops the output after it reaches the first illegal triangle, is there a way to make it keep going and print all "legal" triangles'

Comment: Then you need to trap the exception when you call `Triangle triangle = new Triangle(side1, side2, side3, color, filled);`, printing the value if nothing goes wrong and printing the exception when it does (within the `catch` clause

Comment: So would it be something like try { Triangle triangle = new Triangle(...); catch{ IllegalTriangleException ?

Comment: Yep, but you'll need to add the `System.out.println(triangle);` within the `try` area, before the `catch` statement...